# Update a column in SQL based on groupby

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a column SortOrder in sql based on row count. The column name is SortOrder and the ASP.net will display the column 'reportdisplayname' based on sort order. The 'reportdisplayname' column are all grouped. Below, reportdisplayname has data 'FADMS - Test', 'FADMS - Subject'. The idea of sortorder is to display similar values together. So, 'FADMS - Subject' will appear after 'FADMS - Test'.

```
UPDATE managementreports
SET sortorder = rownum
where eventid = 'xxxxx';

UPDATE managementreports SET sortorder = 9
where eventid = 'xxx' and reportdisplayname = 'FADMS - Test';

UPDATE managementreports SET sortorder = 10
where eventid = 'xxx' and reportdisplayname = 'Results - xxx';

UPDATE managementreports
SET sortorder = sortorder + 1
where eventid = 'xxx' and sortorder > 10;
```

Is there any better way to do this. Currently, I set a sortorder for a new field 'FADMS - Test', then update the sortorder of the existing unrelated field by 1.

Comment: You can use case expressions to "merge" updates into one update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `CASE` expression to update all at once as below:

```
UPDATE managementreports
SET sortorder = CASE 
                    WHEN eventid = 'xxxxx' THEN rownum
                    WHEN eventid = 'xxx' AND reportdisplayname = 'FADMS - Test' THEN 9
                    WHEN eventid = 'xxx' AND reportdisplayname = 'Results - xxx' THEN 10
                    WHEN eventid = 'xxx' AND sortorder > 10 THEN (sortorder + 1)
                    ELSE sortorder
                END
```

Comment: Note that this will set all other rows' sortorder to null.

Comment: Noted, Added `else` condition for the safe side :) Thanks @jarlh

Comment: Or add a WHERE clause, to keep transaction size down.